# Calculate standard error for very large number of observations

Tags: standard-error, large-data

I have a very large dataset (with > 2 million simulated values). I want to compute standard error for this dataset. To do that, I divide the standard deviation by square root of number of observations. However, because of the large number of observations, the standard error is quite low. Is there a way to subsample instead and compute standard error?

Comment: At first glance, it's not obvious why the standard error calculated as (std dev)/sqrt(n) *wouldn't* be "statistically valid".  Can you clarify?

Comment: @BenBolker, the standard error is statistically valid. However, it is artificially low because of the large `n`. I should have phrased it better

Comment: @BenBolker, I have updated question to remove the statistcally valid phrase

Comment: By the law of large numbers, the mean is a consistent estimator under relatively weak assumptions. As such, its standard deviation (aka standard error) will approach 0 for large n. There is nothing wrong with the formula for large n.

Comment: @MichaelM, post as answer?

Comment: to follow up: why do you think it's **artificially** low?  Can you tell us what it is about the small value of the standard error that's problematic for you?

Comment: @BenBolker, the dataset is based on model simulations. The model is an approximation and generally gives moderate matches to observations, this is why I said that the standard error is artificially low

Comment: What is it you think the standard error measures?

Comment: There is nothing artificial about it being low. If you want to simulate a smaller data set, then just simulate fewer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a large sample (>2M), by the Strong Law of Large Numbers, the sample variance will converge to the population variance *almost surely*. 
See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243348/sample-variance-converge-almost-surely

The standard error is a good estimate of the population variance when you have small samples. The standard error is the variance of the sample mean in the sampling distribution.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your second paragraph. (1) what do you mean by "significant"? (2) why should the second sentence only be true for small samples?

Comment: My bad. Made a few edits. Applies for all sample sizes, as you rightly pointed out.

Comment: Standard error is $\sqrt{\dfrac{Var}{n}}$, and as such is a biased estimate of error, worse for small $n$. It is not a variance, *per se*.